# SystemVerilog error: Can't unroll generate for; Unable to unroll loop

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, system-verilog, encoding

I am trying to write a code that converts binary to thermometer code. Thermometer (a.k.a. unary) coding is frequently used in digital systems applications to represent a natural number.

In a thermometer code, an N-bit binary number is represented by a (2 ** N)-bit digital word, which has m zeros followed by (N - m) ones or vice-versa. Basically, if you have a 4-bit binary number say 0110 (decimal is 6), the equivalent thermometer code will be of width 2^4 (=16), and its value will be 6 ones following 10 zeroes (0000000000111111).

```
module model (
    input [7:0] din,
    output reg [255:0] dout
);

logic [255:0] tempout;
int count;

always @ (*) begin
    count  <= din;
    tempout<= '0;
end

generate
    for (genvar i=0; i <= count; i++) begin
        tempout[i] = 1;
    end
endgenerate

assign dout = tempout;
endmodule
```

I am getting the following error for this code:

```
%Error:  Loop unrolling failed.
%Error-UNSUPPORTED:  Unsupported: Can't unroll generate for; Unable to unroll loop
For error description see https://verilator.org/warn/UNSUPPORTED?v=4.228
```

What is wrong with my code?

I have a working code also, but it goes through the loop 2^N number of times, and I want to reduce that.

```
localparam LP_DATA_SIZE = 8;

generate

    for (genvar i = 0; i < 2**LP_DATA_SIZE; i++) begin
        assign dout[i] = (i <= din);
    end

endgenerate
```

Comment: Your "working  code" is the correct way to do this. The number of iterations of a `for` loop must be known at compile time; it can't be controlled by an input port.

Comment: +1 Congrats for the well written question.  *"it goes through the loop 2^N number of times"* It actually doesn't. It as hardware description language, and your interpretation seems to be more related to software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is wrong with my code?

You get the Verilator error message because the `generate` `for` loop needs a constant for the end condition, not a variable.  You can't use `count` for the end condition because it is a variable (`int`).  Your "working code" correctly uses a constant (`localparam`) for the end condition.

Another problem with the code is that the following assignment to `tempout` either needs the `assign` keyword, or it must be inside an `always` block inside the `generate` construct:

```
tempout[i] = 1;
```

Also, you would be making assignments to `tempout` from multiple places (the 1st `always` block and the  `generate`) which would cause contention.

> it goes through the loop 2^N number of times, and I want to reduce
> that.

There is no concern for your working code.  That is the proper way to describe the hardware you want.  The `for` loop simply creates 256 parallel assignments (one for each bit of `dout`), which is what you are trying to achieve.